# Python (online course) exercise

Tags: python

Rewrite pay computation with time-and-a-half for overtime and create a function called computepay which takes two parameters (hours and rate). Normal hour is 40 and the rate is $10. That's $400. But overtime is 5 hours and $15 rate. That's $75. In total, it's $475. So, how would I represent this in python? Here is where I am stuck...

```html
def computepay(hours, rate):
    print(hours * rate)
computepay(40,10)
x = computepay

def computepay2(hours, rate):
    print(hours * rate)
computepay2(5,15)
y = computepay2
```

So, how would I add computepay1 with computepay2?
For now I used x as computepay1 and y with computepay 2, I was thinking maybe add, totalpay = X + Y   then print(totalpay)  ?

Comment: If you work 45 hours, that's 40 hours at the regular rate and 5 hours at the overtime rate. You have to check if `hours` is greater than 40, and if it is, by how much. You also need to compute the overtime rate from the given normal rate `rate`.

Comment: `computepay(40,10) + computepay(5,15)`. There's tons of way to get the answer. Just figure out which one you like most

Comment: `total = (normal_pay - (overtime_hours * rate)) + (overtime_hours * overtime_rate)` for the calculation that you requested.

Comment: This is not really a programming question, but a math question: ask yourself how you arrived at the answer $475 and try programming those same formal steps.

Answer (score 0):

```
def computepay(hours, rate):
    return (hours * rate)

hours_worked = 45
overtime_hours = 0

if hours_worked > 40 :
    overtime_hours = hours_worked - 40
    regular_hours = 40
else : regular_hours = hours_worked

total_pay = computepay (regular_hours, 10) + computepay (overtime_hours, 15)
print ('Total pay is ${:,.2f}'. format (total_pay))
```